# ConvergenceWarning: Stochastic Optimizer: Maximum iterations reached and the optimization hasn't converged yet

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to find the optimal lambda for MLP model. 
For this I've created a list with few values and I'm running the MLP model with each of this value and calculating the score to see which value gives me the highest score. 
I'm receiving this warning:

> ConvergenceWarning: Stochastic Optimizer: Maximum iterations (200) reached and the optimization hasn't converged yet.
>     % self.max_iter, ConvergenceWarning)

Furthermore, I'm getting the same score for each of this values.

Here's my code:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
powers = range(-1,5)
alphas = [10**(p) for p in powers]
print(alphas)

mlp_score_list = []
for alpha in alphas:
   mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes = (20,), max_iter = 200, solver = 'sgd',
                   verbose = False, tol = 1e-4, random_state = 1,
                   learning_rate_init = .1, alpha = a)
mlp.fit(train_data, train_labels)
score = mlp.score(validation_data, validation_labels)
mlp_score_list.append(score)

print(mlp_score_list)

alpha_opt_mlp = alphas[mlp_score_list.index(max(mlp_score_list))] 
print("The optimal lambda is: ",alpha_opt_mlp)
```

Comment: Try using `max_iter = 1000`.This warning tells you that your model hasn't learned (converged) yet. I don't know the type of your data, but increasing the number of iterations could be helpful.

Comment: @Anwarvic I've tried with max_iter = 500,1000 and still the same.

Comment: set `verbose=True` and tell me the last few error values

Comment: Iteration 197, loss = nan
Iteration 198, loss = nan
Iteration 199, loss = nan
Iteration 200, loss = nan

Comment: Let's try something, try using `MLPClassifier` without `alpha` with increasing `max_iter=1000` and see if it works

Comment: Still the same warning

Comment: Can you share the data? Upload your data into a cloud-service and then post the links in your question. Also, post any preprocessing steps if found